# org-mode: Visible export of drawer

Tags: emacs, org-mode

What I want is really to be able to export the :PROPERTIES: of my items and somehow override the default hide behavior. That is apparently impossible. Next best thing is to define a "drawer." So :MYDRAWER: is something I can define -- and it will appear on an export. My problem is drawers don't allow the nice key:value subcategories of properties. With properties I can do this:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:Author: Victor Andrade
:Author2:
:Title: My Missions for Revolutionary Bolivia, 1944-1962
:Subtitle:
:Published: 1976
:Read: 2010
:Subject: History
:Area: Bolivia
:Comments:
:END:
```

But I can't do that with drawers. Trying to add key:value categories between :MYDRAWER: and :END: just gets treated as text. Is there any way for me to have nice properties-like layout get exported? And again, I'm not really sure what to do with the org-mode customization option either (...group Org Export\Org Export General\Org Export With Drawers. I'm guessing all drawers are exported unless you set this not to. Right?

Answer (score 7):

Try something such as:

```
#+OPTIONS: d:(not "MYDRAWER")
```

Comment: Or set `org-export-with-drawers` globally.